Who is the person on the statue in front of the Charms Class in Hogwarts Legacy?
If you go to the Charms Class in Hogwarts Legacy, then right in front of the entrance door, there is a massive statue of someone:

What person is this statue based on? Who is on the statue? Why was there a statue made of this person?
Does anyone know anything about this statue or the person on the statue?
